# Magento2 Add to Cart from homepage not working

Tags: magento2, addtocart, widget, new-products

I've set up a Magento v2.0.6 installation Running Luma theme. I've created a own template based on the Luma with some minor changes (removing links, adding custom CSS etc.) at least nothing big.

I'm only encounter the following issue on the homepage with the following options(that I tried): 'catalog product widget list, and the 'catalog new product widget list.

The widget itself appears normally, only when pressing the 'add to cart' button, the button doesn't change and the page refreshes. You do get the Magento Message that the product has been added to the cart. (despite the fact that the cart still shows as empty).

When going to a product page and adding an other product to the cart, you see the 'add to cart' button state changing to 'adding', and the cart is being updated. (Only now suddenly two products appear, the one that has been added from the homepage appears only when adding an other product from the category/product pages).

Can anyone suggest where the issue may lie ? I haven't changed anything in the files regarding these files (not even remotely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution (for no clarified reason) was to enable all Magento caching options. This solved the issue for me.

Tested this again in a new install: Fresh Luma templated with new product widget on the front page, with caching disabled. The 'Add to Cart' button wouldn't function as expected.

Enabled all Magento2 caching options, and the problem was immediatly fixed

Comment: oh wow, this worked! You should accept your own answer.
Having a fix for caching disabled sites would be nice, too but as workaround this definitely does it :)

Comment: Just did, thanks for replying, glad it worked for you too!